# bundle valued form over $\mathbb{C}P^1$

Tags: complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

Suppose $L$ is a line bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^1$, I wonder how to determine whether $H^{0,1}(\mathbb{C}P^1,L)$ is $0$ or not.

I want to use kodaira vanishing theorem at first, but in my case the assumption of kodaira vanishing theorem does not hold whatever $L$ is positive or anti-positive, I guess the answer depends on the sign of first Chern class, but I have no idea to calculate it, can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $H^{0,1}(\mathbb{CP}^1,L)?$ Do you mean $H^1(\mathbb{CP}^1,L),$ calculated using the Dolbeault resolution? If so then you can apply Serre duality to get that your cohomology is equal to $H^0(\mathbb{CP}^1,K\otimes L^{-1}).$ Then you write $L\cong\mathcal O(n)$ and now you just need that $-2-n\ge 0,$ i.e. $n\le -2.$

Comment: @D.Brogan Thank you! I'm not the original question asker, but may I ask: what is the $K$ in your notation?

Comment: @D.Brogan Yes! I mean this cohomology, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IndraneelTambe2 By $K$ I mean the canonical line bundle on $\mathbb{CP}^1$ which is isomorphic to $\mathcal O(-2).$